# PHP array that outputs field names and values as variables

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am struggling a little bit with a tricky PHP array. I am trying to retrieve data from a database (a single row) and I want to plug this data in a bunch of dynamically generated fields on the page (PHP).

My DB is organised as follows

```
 ____________________________
| cats | dogs | birds | cows |
_____________________________   
|  30  |  40  |  22   |  34  |
______________________________
```

I would like to build an array like this:

```
array(
       $cats => $cats_value
       $dogs => $dogs_value
       etc...
       )
```

**Importantly**: I want the array to ouput variables, where in the above example $cats outputs "cats" and $cats_value outputs "30". I am guessing once this is done that I can use the variable names directly, so I won't have to go nuts trying to pull them out of the array...

I have tried to put various bits of code but have failed miserably (i.e. nothing to show/embarrass myself with on here.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you get this from the DB and let whatever driver you use hydrate it as an associative array, you will already have it like `array('cats' => 30, 'dogs' => 40, ... )`

Comment: You're looking for the `foreach()` construct. [PHP.net](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: What @MarcellFülöp said, then what I said, together, is the actual answer.

Comment: Guys, can you show me how to get that? I have tried many bits of code with no success. Am pulling my hair out...  Will mark any answer that works as correct!

Comment: I appreciate the comments so far, but they are only hinting at a possible solution :-)

Comment: Did you try foreach($resultArray as $key=>$value){ echo $key; echo $value;}

Comment: Sany, how would I prepare the array for this loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the code that provides the answer is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM animals";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$data_array = array();
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);

foreach($row as $key=>$value){ echo $key; echo $value;

${$key}=$key;
${$key."_value"}=$value;

}

echo "<br><br><br>";

echo $Cats." = ".$Cats_value."<br>"; 
echo $Dogs." = ".$Dogs_value."<br>"; 
echo ${"Cows"}." = ".$Cows_value."<br>"; 
echo ${"Birds"}." = ".$Birds_value."<br>";
```

I appreciate all the answers that helped me find the answer to this. As an aside, the whole reason I am doing this is because I need to populate a dynamically generated PHP page with a bunch of variables, and that I will likely need to populate these variables dynamically as well.

If you think I am approaching this problem the wrong way, then please let me know (i.e. is it dumb to convert an associative array into a bunch of $variables? Does that make sense, and/or could it really slow down my page?)